# How to disable already selected items in the dropdown list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a week schedule. when I am trying to select the already selected item it will get disabled. In my form I am looking to edit the weekdays. If monday is selected then it can't be selected again.

```
<?
$i=1;
foreach($shop_timing->result() as $name)
{?>

<br>
<input type="hidden" id="shop_time_id" name="time<?echo $i;?>" value="<?echo $name->shop_time_id;?>">
<select class="right" data-placeholder="select your category" id="select_7<?echo $i?>" data-rel="chosen" name="day<?echo $i;?>" > 
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Monday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?> >Monday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Tuesday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Tuesday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Wednesday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Wednesday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Thursday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Thursday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Friday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Friday</option> 
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Saturday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Saturday</option> 
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Sunday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Sunday</option>  
    -->
</select>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">       
    <div class="input-group"> 
          <input type="text" class="timepicker starttime" value="<?echo $name->working_start_time?>" name="timefrom<?echo $i;?>" id="timefrom" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>  
</div> 
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">       
    <div class="input-group">             
        <input type="text" class="timepicker end" value="<?echo $name->working_end_time?>" name="endtime<?echo $i;?>" id="endtime" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>
</div>  

<? $i++; } ?> 

<input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="<?echo $count;?>">

<?
for($j=1;$j<=(7-$count);$j++) 
{?>

<select class="right" data-placeholder="select your category" id="select_7<?echo $i?>" data-rel="chosen" name="day<?echo $i;?>"> 
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
    <option>Thursday</option>
    <option>Friday</option> 
    <option>Saturday</option> 
    <option>Sunday</option> 
</select>  

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">       
    <div class="input-group">           
        <input type="text" class="timepicker starttime" name="timefrom<?echo $i;?>" id="starttime3" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>  
</div> 
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">       
    <div class="input-group">             
        <input type="text" class="timepicker end" name="endtime<?echo $i;?>" id="endtime3" placeholder="time"/>                             
    </div>
</div>  

<? $i++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all for the purpose of DRY, don't repeat yourself.  The easy way to build your select is with an array and a loop .  Typically it would take this form

```
<?php

    function printOptions( $selected_value )
        $days = array(
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"
        );

        foreach( $days as $day ){
            if($selected_value == $day ){
                $selected = ' selected="selected"';
            }else{
                $selected = '';
            }

            echo '<option value="'.$day.'"'.$selected.' >'.$day.'</option>'
        }
    }
?>
```

Then you can go

```
<select class="right day_selection" data-placeholder="select your category" id="select_7<?echo $i?>" data-rel="chosen" name="day<?echo $i;?>" > 
<?php printOptions( $name->working_day ) ?>
</select>
```

Isn't that much nicer looking

That settled this is largely a javascript problem so with jquery you would want to do something like this:

```
  var selectors = $('day_selection'); //cache select elments

 $('.day_selection').change( function(){
      var current = $(this).prop('id');
      var current_value = $(this).val();
      $.each( selectors, function(i,v){
          if($(this).prop('id') != current ){
           $(this).find('option[value="'+current_value+'"]').prop('disabled', true );

         }
      });
 });
```

now you will have to find a way to un-disable them but that should point you in the right direction.  Likely you could make an object to store the values in and then when they change look up that value and `disable,false` them.

Like this

```
   var selected = {
         "select_71" : "Monday" //Id : value 
   }
```

And below this

```
  $(this).find('option[value="'+current_value+'"]').prop('disabled', true );
```

Add

```
 if( selected.current ){
     $(this).find('option[value="'+selected.current+'"]').prop('disabled', false );
  }
```

And outside ( after ) the each loop add:

```
  selected.current = current_value;
```

On a side note an Idea that occurs to me is why have the selects at all, why not just have blocks with a checkbox and the time range, checking the checkbox selects the day.  Then there is no need to worry about it and the order is fixed.

**Thursday 8/20/2015**      [ ] select

[_ start time *] to [* end time _]

**Friday 8/21/2015**      [ ] select

[_ start time *] to [* end time _]

etc...

Comment: I feel like this deserves something purely for the effort you put into it. But it does not address the question in any way shape or form. Maybe you should get registered over on the CodeReview site.

Comment: How does the javascript in my answer not address this?  In fact I think you should pay better attention to the code that was supplied

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select multiple items in a dropdown but you have not told the dropdown that multiple selection is allowed. I think this is confusing things

On your `<select..>` add the `multiple` attribute like so

```
<select multiple 
      class="right" 
      data-placeholder="select your category"
      id="select_7<?echo $i?>" 
      data-rel="chosen" 
      name="day<?echo $i;?>" >
```

Comment: You might want to read the supplied code better, specifically `foreach($shop_timing->result() as $name)` because that first select lies within this foreach loop. Therefore, the selection takes place in multiple selects.  Now I am not saying that is the optimal way to do it, but that is what was supplied.  Ah ... in fact so does the second one.

Comment: Further, there is an attached time component to each day selection, so simply changing the select to multiple, isn't really an option..

Comment: Maybe you are rignt, I read that as meaning when a preselected (`selected="selected"`) day is clicked it cannot be clicked again i.e. it becomes disabled. I therefore thought this may be simply due to the fact that the `<select>` did not have the `multiple` attribute set.

Comment: I'm not always right, but I am never wrong. That's my motto .. lol .. In any case it seems messy to have so many selects, so hard to tell without having the full code for it, if there would be a better way.  Perhaps just static blocks for the days, with a time range, and a checkbox for each to enable them would be cleaner setup.